# DaVinci Resolve 16 shows black screen on imported media

Tags: davinci-resolve

This is my first time using this software cause I am trying to learn. but when I import my media, it shows all black screen and all I can hear was audio.

File imported are .mp4

[image: da]

Comment: Ask this question over at the blackmagic DaVinci user forum.  Their devs and admins are super responsive and helpful.  Be sure to post your system specs when you do.  To me, it looks like your hardware isn't up to snuff, but they'll know for sure.  https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewforum.php?f=21&sid=afb1a543265160c1a4dacdcda8c81247

Comment: ... or post your specs here.  We'd need those to be able to diagnose, as well.

Comment: I have the same issue, it seems to be an incompatibility with the new hardware acceleration in V.16 and AMD video cards. Resolve staff just blame AMD when questioned. But several driver updates have come out since the earliest report of this bug (even a few since I have had the issue), and nothing has changed. Sadly, there isn't a solution yet so if you're looking for a free video editor to get started I would go for HitFilm Express.

Comment: Do you have AMD's RX 560 or 580? I have had the same issue with both cards with DR16 on two different machines. In both cases removing all video drivers completely and reinstalling AMD's latest drivers fixed the issue.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue. Updated my Nvidia driver and now I just get a grey screen. Audio plays fine though... I hate technology... :'(

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using an unsupported codec.  Are you using the Linux for windows version?  What is the video you are trying to import encoded as?

Comment: Judging by the windows 10 logo in the lower left corner I'd guess it's not Linux. But apart from that it *does* look like a codec issue